# SQLite get row data using SELECT

Tags: android, database, sqlite, select

Using SQLite Database, I have a table with 6 columns in each row as the rows are added. The first column is the name of the "person." I have it so when you click on the person in a listview, it brings up a screen with 5 edit texts. You fill them out and submit it and it adds it to another row in the database.

To retrieve that data later on, I am trying to use SELECT by the name to get it, but cannot figure out how this works.

```
 public Cursor getChildRulesInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name) {
    dop.getReadableDatabase().execSQL("SELECT * FROM "+CHILD_RULES_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+CHILD_NAME + "=\""+ name+"\"");
}
```

What do I do with that to retreive every column inside of that specific row. I am confused on the process to get it out.

Any lead in the write direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public Cursor getChildRulesInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name) {
return dop.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+CHILD_RULES_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+CHILD_NAME+" = '"+ name+"' ", null);}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use execSql for getting data, that is only for sending data to the database. Instead, use rawQuery if you want to use the String. So it would be:

```
public Cursor getChildRulesInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name) {
    return dop.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+CHILD_RULES_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+CHILD_NAME + "='"+ name+"'", null);
}
```

This will return you the cursor object that you are looking for.

Comment: So that will return the cursor at the location of the row that has the "name" I am looking for? Then use that cursor to select each file out. Thanks for the quick response. I'll try it now and see.

Comment: Yup. You will generally want to do `if(cursor.moveToFirst()){ // use the cursor's data }` to make sure the cursor actually has data. If you don't check first and it came back empty and you try to use the data, your app will crash.

Comment: That makes sense. To delete a row I used the delete method and it worked. But now that is saying that it cannot find a row "Zack", even though I just added one. Is that code inside the rawQuery correct? In the delete one I had this ------>       dop.getWritableDatabase().delete("child_info","child_name = ?", new String[] { name });